# Set HBox as title for TitledPane

Tags: javafx

Putting a custom node as content on a TitledPane is fairly easy, but how can I set a node as the title of a TitledPane?

Can't really find anything on the subject, to a point where I start thinking it's not possible to do something other than

`titledPane.setText("My title")`

But that can't be, can it ?

Comment: Actually the TitledPane has always an HBox as [title](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane)... Then I am not sure to understand your purpose.

Comment: @Pagbo Well, I want to know how I can put my own HBox as the title OR add my own Nodes to the title's HBox

Comment: @fabien 's answer should do the trick then (as always or almost).

Comment: @Pagbo yep it does, hadn't seen it yet when I wrote the comment. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `graphic` property of the `TitledPane`:

```
HBox hbox = ...
TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
titledPane.setGraphic(hbox);
```